# Hibernate, Spring and foreign keys

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations, foreign-keys

I'm working on a hibernate, spring project to help me understand the basics of those two.
I'm running into a problem where i want to be able to add foreign keys to my tables.

I've been browsing the internet for information regarding this subject and I haven't been able to find something that suits my needs.

I have two classes:

```
 Schools
 Classes
```

Now i want to map the primary key from Schools to Classes.

This is the code I have now:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SCHOOL_ID", table = "SCHOOL")
private School school;
```

and for my getter and setter:

```
public long getSchool() {
    return school.getId();
}

public void setSchool(long schoolId) {
    this.school.setId(schoolId);
}
```

Is this the way to go? Or am I totally looking at it the wrong way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you are on the right track, although its better to deal with the actual objects and not the ids e.g.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SCHOOL_ID", table = "SCHOOL")
private School school;


public School getSchool() {
    return school;
}

public void setSchool(School school) {
    this.school=school;
}
```

Comment: I am kind of having a similar situation..with this mapping though can you stop inserting a class in the table which has a school that is present in the school table?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this :

```
public long getSchool() {
    return this.school;
}

public void setSchool(School school) {
    this.school = school;
}
```

Comment: Downvoted as the answer is both incorrect (the code with just the proposed changes would no longer compile as OP clearly defines `school` as of type `School`, not `long`) and the answer doesn't explain the rationale behind why this would be a good or correct change.